# Convert flat list to objects

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a flat structure into a hierarchy.

The list looks like this where personid, first and lastname occurs more than once:

```
public class VisitType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string VisitName { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeTo { get; set; }

}
```

And I want to convert it to look like this instead where the client only occurs once and every visit is grouped under:

```
public class Client {

    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }

    public Visit[] Visits { get; set; }
}
public class Visit {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartBefore { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartAfter { get; set; }

}
```

What is the fastest way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: I've tried some form of grouping using linq but cant get it right. Also I'm wondering of it is the fastest?

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try that in LinqPad

```
var list = new []{
    new { PersonId = 1, Name = "Is", Lastname = "Shin", VisitName = "a" },
    new { PersonId = 1, Name = "Is", Lastname = "Shin", VisitName = "b" },
};

(
from i in list
group i by i.PersonId into g
let first = g.First()
select new {
    Person = new { ID = first.PersonId, Name = first.Name, Lastname = first.Lastname },
    Visits = g.Select(gi => new { VisitName = gi.VisitName } )
}
).Dump();
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick. Going to try it out a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, the same query using [method syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx), that I personally prefer:

```
var result = visitLists.GroupBy(vt => vt.PersonId, (g, e) => 
    new
    {
        First = e.First(),
        List = e
    }).Select(i =>
    new Client()
    {
        FirstName = i.First.FirstName,
        LastName = i.First.LastName,
        PersonId = i.First.PersonId,
        Visits = i.List.Select(vt => new Visit()
                {
                    Name = vt.VisitName,
                    StartAfter =  vt.TimeFrom,
                    StartBefore = vt.TimeTo
                }).ToArray()
    }).ToList();
```